# Remove password field from django admin panel

Tags: python, django

I have implemented search and filtering for ***Post*** class in Django admin panel. ***Post*** class has no password filed but a password field appeared in admin panel. I want to remove it from admin panel.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/2daXilT]

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.db import models
from .models import Post, Comment

class PostAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ordering = ('created_at',)
    list_display = ('author', 'blood_group', 'required_bags', 'contact_number', 'created_at', 'is_resolved', 'admin_approved')
    search_fields = ('author__name', 'blood_group', 'is_resolved',) # Can not add author as it is a foregin key to post
    readonly_fields = ('created_at',)
    exclude = ('password',)

    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = ()

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
admin.site.register(Comment)
```

I have tried to remove the password field using `exclude = ('password',)` in admin.py of post app. It worked for my ***User*** model that actually had password field. But it is not working for ***Post*** model.

Here is code for forms.py

```
# forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Post, Comment

from django import forms

class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['description', 'address', 'blood_group', 'required_bags', 'deadlineDate', 'deadlineTime', 'contact_number', 'is_resolved']

    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for name, field, in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'form-control'})
        self.fields['deadlineDate'].widget.input_type = 'date'
        self.fields['deadlineTime'].widget.input_type = 'time'
        self.fields['contact_number'].widget.input_type = 'number'
        self.fields['description'].widget.attrs.update({'rows' : '4'})
        self.fields['is_resolved'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'form-check-input'})
```

Here is code for modes.py

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from author.decorators import with_author

BLOOD_GROUPS = [
    ('A+', 'A+'),
    ('A-', 'A-'),
    ('B+', 'B+'),
    ('B-', 'B-'),
    ('AB+', 'AB+'),
    ('AB-', 'AB-'),
    ('O+', 'O+'),
    ('O-', 'O-'),
]

@with_author
class Post(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    blood_group = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=BLOOD_GROUPS)
    required_bags = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    deadlineDate = models.DateField()
    deadlineTime = models.TimeField()
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_resolved = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    admin_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.author) + ", " + str(self.blood_group) + ", " + str(self.address)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me like you should inherit `PostAdmin` from `ModelAdmin`, not `UserAdmin` since your `Post` model is not connected to the `User` model in any way.

```py
# forms.py
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Post, Comment

from django import forms

class PostForm(ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['description', 'address', 'blood_group', 'required_bags', 'deadlineDate', 'deadlineTime', 'contact_number', 'is_resolved']

    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for name, field, in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'form-control'})
        self.fields['deadlineDate'].widget.input_type = 'date'
        self.fields['deadlineTime'].widget.input_type = 'time'
        self.fields['contact_number'].widget.input_type = 'number'
        self.fields['description'].widget.attrs.update({'rows' : '4'})
        self.fields['is_resolved'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'form-check-input'})
```

The `UserAdmin` is for showing the admin page of the `User` model specifically.